# Git: How to push from "no branch" to a new remote branch?

Tags: git, branch, push, remote-branch

I did:

```
git co upstream/master  # To no branch.
<then did a trivial edit on some file...>
git commit -a -m "Trivial edit"
git push origin NewBranch
```

But got this:

```
$ git push origin ignore-netbeans-config
error: src refspec ignore-netbeans-config does not match any.
```

Can I push to a new branch without creating a local one?

Comment: Good question! Of course, if you might do any further editing here, you'd want to go ahead and create a branch to be safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's clear up a few small details first:

1. A branch is a "ref" under the `refs/heads` namespace.  Just `ls .git/refs/heads` and `cat` the files there to see what I mean.
2. A tag is "ref" under the `refs/tags` namespace.  Just ls `.git/refs/tags` to see for yourself.
3. `HEAD` just another "ref", but it's special in the aspect that it can be "symbolic".  Just `cat .git/HEAD` and see what it says.

A `push` operation operates on a "ref", and the default "mapping" preserves the namespace. This means that when I push a branch, it'll appear as a branch on the remote; when I push a tag, it'll appear as a tag on the remote.  Consider the following scenarios:

1. I want to push the tag `moo` and make it appear as a branch on the remote server (yes, I'm essentially "converting" a tag into a branch).  This is how I'll do it:

   `git push origin moo:refs/heads/moo`
2. Git needs a way to differentiate between fast-forward and non-ff pushes, so that people don't end up overwriting other people's work by mistake.  Let's say I want to push the branches `master`, `next`, and `pu`, of which only `pu` is non-ff.  This is how I'll do it (note that you must supply an explicit mapping when you're using `+`):

   `git push origin master next +pu:pu`
3. Now, let's get to your question.  You want to push your `HEAD` so that it appears in the `refs/heads` namespace on the remote as a branch named "ignore-netbeans-config". If this branch didn't exist before, or if you're overwriting some commits in it (ie. non-ff push), use the `+`.  Otherwise, don't.  End result:

   `git push origin +HEAD:refs/heads/ignore-netbeans-config`

TL;DR version: `git push origin +HEAD:refs/heads/ignore-netbeans-config`

Answer (score 11):

try

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/ignore-netbeans-config
```

Comment: You should be able to omit the "refs/heads/" part of it.

Comment: I guess if it doesn't exist yet you have to be explicit.